# Swift - println Not Printing to Console

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, println

The following code either runs or does not run the line `println("test")`, which results in nothing bring printed to the console:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!
    
    @IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle
        println("test")
    }
    
}
```

Relating to the following GUI:
[image: Screenshot of GUI]

The following is a screenshot of the console after the program is run and one of the number buttons is pressed:
[image: Console after program run and button pressed]

I do not know if the line of code runs nor why, if it does, that it is not printing to the console.

Can someone please show me how to make it print to the console?

Comment: try sender.currentTitle! to unwrap the optional - is your IBAction correctly set up on the digit buttons?

Comment: have you connected the method to those buttons?

Answer (score 1):

First, right click a button. Under `Sent Events` check if there is an event handler set for `Touch Up Inside`. If so, it might be incompatible with your method `appendDigit` (wrong parameters maybe?) so you should disconnect it (using the little `x`).
Next, ctrl-drag from your button to the `appendDigit` method to hook up the event handler again.

Answer (score 0):

I know is a litle late but if you're using **Swift 2**, you can only use print() to write something to the output. Apple has combined both **println()** and **print()** functions into one.

If you want to output something with a newline, you can set the appendNewline parameter to true.

Here is an example:

```
print("Hello new Print with newLine", appendNewline: true)
```